# Boilerplate js file calling methods

Tags: jquery, html, html5boilerplate

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Boilerplate js file calling methods

```
    1- Why calling two times on the same file..? 
    2- What is the different second one calling method..?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The first line loads jQuery from Google's Content Distribution Network (CDN). It's likely that it's already be in someone's cache, so it'll load super-fast for them.
2. The second line literally means `window.jQuery OR load a local copy`. Essentially, if the first line of code succeeded, `window.jQuery` will exist and the bit after the `||` doesn't get executed. If not (site is down, or some other error occurred), the browser jumps to the OR condition, and loads a local copy instead.

Answer (score 1):

First one loads the Jquery from Google CDN servers. Since we are loading from CDN servers, files gets loaded fast. And also you may get benefited from browser cache also (if others use same url in other website).

If first one gets failed due to any reason(cdn server down or some other issue), second one loads from local server (means the current website)

Comment: First preference online calling right ? if online file will be working fine,  first calling method will not work right?

Comment: yes, if first line loads juqery from cdn server, it wont load again!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it checks if you have an internet connection. If it has, the CDN version will be used, otherwise the local one.